# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar la ficha del producto en la página de inicio?

Tags: php, wordpress

He estado buscando por internet y no encuentro nada de cómo hacer lo siguiente.

Me gustaría que en mi Wordpress, en la página de inicio (HOME). Se remplazase por la ficha de producto, solamente en la tienda tengo un único producto para vender en el Woocommerce. He estado revisando en los ajustes del wordpress y woocommerce. Y no encuentro nada.

¿Qué archivos PHP debería tocar?.